# IIS7 and ASP.NET how to throttle user requests

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, bandwidth-throttling

I am using ASP.NET with IIS7 and today a bug in one of my pages caused the server to go down. The script was using ajax to query a resource at a rate of ~1000 requests per second. The requests are authenticated, so I know what user requested what page.

My question is, either via IHttpModule or otherwise, how do I limit at the server-level, the max number of requests per second (or per minute) a client is allowed to make and then introduce a delay so that their requests are throttled?

Answer (score -8, accepted):

Open you IIS manager and select application pool signed to your asp.net application.
Open advanced Settings for this pool and set Request Limit that shuold be greather than 0.

[image]

Comment: Is there anyway to set this limit on a per-host/per-user basis?

Comment: I don't think this is possible out of the box. But you can limit access(allow/deny) by using IP Adress and Domain Restrictions on Web Application level. This way you can ban specific trouble maker IP.

Comment: Just to make this clear, you can limit reqests on a per-host/per-user basis inside .net app but this will not put the heat from IIS off if this is causing the fail.

Comment: Setting Request Limit on Application Pool doesn't limit the number of requests in a given time interval - which is what OP asked. As it says in the description, the limit is the number of requests to process before the application pool is recycled.

Answer (score 4):

If anyone finds their way back here, you can throttle requests per user in IIS 8 and up. The setting is denyRequestByRate. The documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/dynamicipsecurity/denybyrequestrate).